# Python program to perform keyword matches for contents present in two files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nltk, pyscripter

I have used nltk to obtain a list of tokenised keywords. The Output is

```
['Natural', 'Language', 'Processing', 'with', 'PythonNatural', 'Language', 'Processingwith', 'PythonNatural', 'Language', 'Processing', 'with', 'Python', 'Editor', ':', 'Production', 'Editor', ':', 'Copyeditor']
```

I have a text file keyword.txt which contains following keywords:

```
Processing
Editor
Pyscripter
Language
Registry
Python
```

How can i match the keywords obtained from tokenization with my keyword.txt file such that a third file is created for the matched keywords.

This is a program i have been working on, but it creates an union of these two files:

```
import os
with open(r'D:\file3.txt', 'w') as fout:
  keywords_seen = set()
  for filename in r'D:\File1.txt', r'D:\Keyword.txt':
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            keyword = line.strip()
            if keyword not in keywords_seen:
                fout.write(line + "\n")
                keywords_seen.add(keyword)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i match the keywords obtained from tokenization with my keyword.txt file such that a third file is created for the matched keywords

Here's a simple solution, adjust the filenames as needed.

```
# these are the tokens:
tokens = set(['Natural', 'Language', 'Processing', 'with', 'PythonNatural', 'Language', 'Processingwith', 'PythonNatural', 'Language', 'Processing', 'with', 'Python', 'Editor', ':', 'Production', 'Editor', ':', 'Copyeditor'])

# create a set containing the keywords
with open('keywords.txt', 'r') as keywords:
    keyset = set(keywords.read().split())

# write outputfile
with open('matches.txt', 'w') as matches:
    for word in keyset:
        if word in tokens:
            matches.write(word + '\n')
```

This will produce a file `matches.txt` with the words

```
Language
Processing
Python
Editor
```